# Making a connected graph out of n nodes with weighted edges?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a connected graph with n nodes in which all nodes are connected to each other and weighed. How can I create a new connected graph out of the exiting graph such that there are only n-1 edges and edge-sum(sum of weights of all edges used) is minimum?

Comment: Look up Kruskal's algorithm or Prim's algorithm. I'm sure both have been discussed here many times.

Comment: So, have you had a look for those?

Comment: Thanks. It did my work

Comment: Good. Let me encourage you to write up your work and post it as an answer. Then you can accept it by clicking in the check mark next to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem refers to finding the Minimum Spanning Tree. Kruskal's algorithm or Prim's algorithm can do the work. Refer here: Kruskal's Algorithm-
 http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-2-kruskals-minimum-spanning-tree-mst/ Prim's Algorithm- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=27091
Both algorithms yield Minimum spanning trees. Kruskal's algorithm typically works better in sparse graphs and Prim's algorithm works better in dense graphs. So, for this situation where there are a lot of edges(~V^2) Prim's algorithm will work faster.